# Angular 2 - statements inside ng-content resolved when they shouldn't be

Tags: angular

I created a component that shows its ng-content only if a certain obj is not null (it's more complex than that in practice, but let's say this is the case for the sake of this question).

Here's how the component "comp" is used:

`<comp [ref]="obj">
Name: {{obj.name}}
</comp>`

The component's template looks like that:

`<ng-content *ngIf="ref != null"></ng-content>`

The problem is, Angular is trying to resolve {{obj.name}} before it appears in ng-content in comp's template (when obj is null), thus resulting in an error.

I'd like the statements inside ng-content to only be resolved once ng-content is shown. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you are using *content projection* (similar to transclusion) per https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content Angular 2 will attempt to render `Name: {{obj.name}}` before it places that content into your other component.

If the content you're projecting isn't safe to render at all times you'll need to guard against it with an `*ngIf` on the outside or an Elvis operator `{{obj?.name}}` depending on the effect you're going for.

Comment: Is there any way that Angular 2 will not attempt to render Name: {{obj.name}} before it places it into the other component?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you'd have to wrap it in a `span` or another element and apply `*ngIf="obj?.name"`

Comment: Thanks, but that much I kinda already knew, I'm looking for a way to stop Angular 2 from attempting to render it before it places it into the component, for a "cleaner" solution. Hopefully someone familiar with the behind the hood of Angular 2 will have an idea. I appreciate your answer regardless.